# how can i create a master switch in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to create a master switch for ads in my app. For example, if I set ads = false in my activity or class, then it should disable all the ads in my app. If I set ads = true, the it should show ads again.

Comment: Are you asking how to define a boolean variable?

Comment: Yes, like Boolean variable.

Comment: Use SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to store a [shared preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) that you check at the point you're loading your ads.

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preference is the way to go.

Use `putBoolean(boolean)` method.

[Shared Preferences Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)